PostgreSQL - Get duplicate values of an Array
I have a table in which one the columns is an ARRAY of smallint.
ID | Array
--------------------
1 |  [1,2,3]
2 |  [4,5,6]
3 |  [7,8,9]

What I'm looking for is... a function where every time I INSERT new data, it first validates if a value of my new array is already in the table and gets the duplicate values.
I know that OVERLAP(&&) resolves part of the issue, if I insert the array [1,4,11], [1,4] are my duplicate values, but OVERLAP only returns true, what I need is know which values are the one that already exist in the table.

I can't help but think that storing this data as an array when you are wanting to apply logic at that layer of granularity, that this data would be much better suited for a new table that has a unique constraint on the column that stores these values. Otherwise this is going to get compute expensive as your data grows. Is that an option or are you stuck by storing this data in an array in the same table?

If those are integers, there's an & intersection operator in intarray extension that does exactly what you want.

Just to be clear, I'm using the integers as an example, but the reality is the column is an array of strings.

Please update the question to accurately reflect the type of array data. The available approaches/operations can be significantly affected by data types. As @JNevill suggested, an array column is probably not the best choice. What is the use case?

No, there is no way to create a constraint like you want.
If you use a model that follows the first normal form, like
CREATE TABLE item (
   id bigint PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE label (
   id bigint REFERENCES item NOT NULL,
   value smallint NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id, value)
);

it is simple to create the constraint you want:
ALTER TABLE label ADD UNIQUE (value);

